# (roblox) why does all my game data reset when i test in roblox studio

Tags: testing, save, roblox, datastore

so basically when i play in the proper roblox website my data saves everytime so it wouldnt be an issue for actual players but its just when i click test in roblox studio i start from 0 basically giving me a new save file and when i go back in irl roblox it continues from when i tested on roblox studio and not my actual save. obviously this wouldnt be an issue for actual roblox players as they cant play from roblox studio anyway. its just annoying for me for when im testing my game in roblox studio and it resets all my data so i have to start from the beginning if im playing it normally.

Im not sure if its something to do with my datastore script or if i need to enable a setting but if you would like to see the script just lmk. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you don't have API access enabled in the studio. To enable this open your game (in the studio) click home -> game settings -> security -> enable studio access to api services.

Comment: It is actually enabled